# jQuery/JavaScript Function to Change Style Opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, styles

How do I write a function that, onmouseover;

- Gets all the 'img' tags in this div
- Changes style of the image(s) to lower the opacity to 0.5

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is for a website I'm working on, not for school, but as a personal hobby. I'm in high school, and have never gone to any computer science classes.
See my 'about me' for more info.

As for the people who actually helped, thanks, I got it working!

Comment: Yes, what I wanted to point at is that your asking a question without trying something yourself, without posting a sample code and saying "I'm block at that point", you're just asking "write it for me please" and this is not the spirit of stackoverflow.

Comment: I actually tried a few things, and couldn't get it to work. Seriously, I was at it for over half an hour. 

I'm no good with JavaScript... can write a great PHP script though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.whatever').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('img', this).css('opacity', '0.5');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('img', this).css('opacity', '1');
});
```

However, you can do the same thing using using pure CSS:

```
.whatever:hover img { opacity: 0.5; }
```

Comment: the CSS only solution is way better than the Javascript one

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possibility:

```
$("#yourDiv").bind("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).find("img").css("opacity", "0.5");
});
```